# Как добавлять в базу данных данные асинхронно

Tags: c#

В моем приложении я хочу добавить данные в базу, это мой парсер, парсится все асинхронно, и в процессе парсинга UI не блокируется, а вот когда все спарсенные результаты начинают добавляться в базу, тогда происходит блокировка UI.

Пробую сделать асинхронный метод не получается, работаю  с базой через EF.

Вот код метода, который добавляет все результаты в базу:

```
public Task AddRezultinbase()
{
    using (var context = new ResumeData())
    {
        foreach (var item in Big)
        {
            int i = 1;
            context.Mypars.Add(new Resume() { ResumeId = i, VacansName = item.VacansName, Name = item.Name, Expiriens = item.Expiriens, Salary = item.Salary, Foto = item.Foto });
            i++;
        }

        context.SaveChanges();

    }

}
```

Это свойство:

```
DbSet   public  DbSet<Resume> Mypars { get; set; }
```

Как сделать этот метод асинхронным?

Comment: Используйте асинхронные методы [EF](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/8.1.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Практически все методы EF имеют аналогичный асинхронный метод.

Асинхронные выборки:

```
return await this.ApplicationDbContext.Gamedays
                 .Include(x => x.Place)
                 .AsNoTracking()
                 .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
```

Асинхронное обновление и сохранение:

```
this.ApplicationDbContext.Gamedays.Update(entity);
await this.ApplicationDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

И так далее.

Соответственно, вам достаточно заменить одну строку:

```
context.SaveChanges();
```

на

```
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Ну и не забыть добавить в метод указание на async.